# Hide members of classes outside cs file, but accessible for classes within the file

Tags: c#

If I have a cs file with 2 classes, and want to protect the members of my classes from the outside world, but let the classes have access to all members within the same file. Can this be done?

Guess I want the access modifier "internal" not te be working on the complete App_Code folder, but on this one file.

Simplified example:

```
public class Comments {
    private static List<CommentRecord> Records = new List<CommentRecord>();
    static Comments() {
        LoadFromDatabase();
    }

    public static void LoadFromDatabase() {
        // load and loop to fill data...
        CommentRecord comment = new CommentRecord();
        comment.Id = ...
        comment.ParentId = ...
        comment.Text = ...
        Records.Add(comment);
    }

    public static CommentRecord FindById(Int32 id) {
        return Records.Find(delegate(CommentRecord x){return x.Id == id;});
    }
}

public class CommentRecord {
    public Int32 Id = 0;
    public Int32 ParentId = 0;
    public String Text = "";

    public void Save() {
        // save...
    }
}
```

I do not want other outside classes to be touching the Id field, but the Comments class, in the same file, should be able to set it.

- Making Id a property can make it Read Only for the outside world, but then I can not update it via the Comments class either.
- Making Id private would not grant access to it by the Comments class.
- Making Id internal would grant access to Comments class, but also to everything else in the App_Code folder

Comment: Just use constructor.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad The `internal` keyword makes a class accessible to the *assembly*, not the *namespace*. That said, I would say that if you really need a class only to be accessible to a small number of other classes (for some reason), they should probably be in their own assembly anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a public interface, with a private inner class, so only Comments class can touch CommentsRecord.

```
public interface ICommentRecord
{
    int Id { get; }
    // Expose any other public members you want
}

public class Comments
{
    private static List<CommentRecord> Records = new List<CommentRecord>();
    static Comments()
    {
        LoadFromDatabase();
    }

    public static void LoadFromDatabase()
    {
        // load and loop to fill data...
        CommentRecord comment = new CommentRecord();
        comment.Id = 2;
        Records.Add(comment);
    }

    // Make this returnn the public interface
    public static ICommentRecord FindById(Int32 id)
    {
        return Records.Find(delegate(CommentRecord x) { return x.Id == id; });
    }

    // Make this class private to Comments class. So its only accessible from within Comments
    private class CommentRecord : ICommentRecord
    {
        public int Id { get; internal set; }  
    }

}
```

Your other option is to put your classes in a separate assembly, and use `internal`

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, not possible.

You can get close by nesting the `Comments` class *inside* the `CommentRecord` class, where it would be able to access `private` members of the `CommentsRecord` class. But that's not a good solution unless you have some other valid reason to nest the class that way. If you don't, then you should just use `internal`, and accept that other code within the same project might be able to change it.

Even better IMHO would be make the field read-only (either as a field or property) and to not grant the `Comments` class access to the property setter. Instead, design the class as an immutable type and require the `Comments` class to pass the correct values to the constructor. Without more context it's impossible to know for sure whether that would work in your case, but it certainly would be a superior design.